# Bug opengraph subdomains

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I was doing some tests with opengraph, all worked fine on my subdomain dev.site.com so i activated it.

I tried to use it on my website site.com and i get this error:

{"error":{"message":"(#100) Application does not own 252217774887165 action type","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

I tried to delete one action and declare a new one (i thought maybe it is because a declare them with the dev.site url) but i still get this error even for a new action wich is not activated.

I didn't find anything on the web about this bug...

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure you're initialising the SDK with the correct app ID? is that a global or custom action? how are you trying to use the action? is it already approved?

Comment: Hello, Yes i am sure, id use git so there is no difference between my both website "dev.website.com" and "website.com" and it works on the first one wich i activated my actions.